# Do firstborns have a higher IQ?

Tags: neurology, intelligence

I've seen number of articles telling about the fact that firstborns are more likely to have higher IQ than their sibilings.

Sources:

1. [Research Finds Firstborns Gain the Higher I.Q.](http://www.nytimes.com/2007/06/22/science/22sibling.html?pagewanted=all),
2. [Study: Older Siblings Have Higher IQs](http://www.livescience.com/1651-study-older-siblings-higher-iqs.html),
3. [First-borns 'really do have a a higher IQ'](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-463761/First-borns-really-a-higher-IQ.html).

Is that true?

Comment: As a first born, I'd say the answer is: no.

Comment: ...I mean YES!!

Comment: Better question: is the IQ a reasonable way of expressing intelligence with all its facets? ;) ... still +1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Birth order does not influence IQ but social rank in the family does.

> Birth order is not associated with intelligence in between-family data once the number of siblings is statistically controlled. The analyses support the admixture hypothesis, which avers that the apparent birth-order effect on intelligence is an artifact of family size, and cast doubt on the confluence and resource dilution models, both of which claim that birth order has a causal influence on children's cognitive development. **The analyses suggest that birth order has no genuine causal effect on general intelligence.** <sup>[1]</sup>
>
> It appears that although low-IQ parents have been making large families, large families do not make low-IQ children in modern U.S. society. **The apparent relation between birth order and intelligence has been a methodological illusion.** <sup>[2]</sup>
>
> One family of hypotheses suggests that the relation between birth order and intelligence is due to more-favorable family interaction and stimulation of low-birth-order children, whereas others claim that the effect is caused by prenatal gestational factors. We show that **intelligence quotient (IQ) score levels** among nearly 250,000 military conscripts **were dependent on social rank in the family and not on birth order** as such, providing support for a family interaction explanation. <sup>[3]</sup>

---

References:

1. Kanazawa S. [Intelligence, birth order, and family size.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22581677) Pers Soc Psychol Bull 2012 Sep;38(9):1157-64. doi: [10.1177/0146167212445911](http://dx.doi.org/10.1177/0146167212445911). PubMed PMID: 22581677.
2. Rodgers JL, Cleveland HH, van den Oord E, Rowe DC. [Resolving the debate over birth order, family size, and intelligence.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10892201) Am Psychol 2000 Jun;55(6):599-612. PubMed PMID: 10892201.
3. Kristensen P, Bjerkedal T. [Explaining the relation between birth order and intelligence.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17588924) Science 2007 Jun;316(5832):1717. doi: [10.1126/science.1141493](http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1141493). PubMed PMID: 17588924.

Comment: What is the answer then?

Comment: @Articuno: I doubt there is much of a conclusion to be found here (beyond "inconclusive").

Comment: @Articuno: I am reading the conclusion as "Yes, there is correlation. No, there is not causation, due to a confounding factor."